# Why does Michael Fassbender have blonde hair in Steve Jobs?

Tags: steve-jobs

This is not James Bond. Steve Jobs was a real person. And Steve Jobs never had blond hair. Heck, Michael Fassbender doesn't even have naturally blonde hair. His hair is a dark brown. Why would the filmmakers go out of their way to make him look nothing like Steve Jobs when the movie is called Steve Jobs?

Comment: Does he? I haven't seen the film, but in [this extended trailer](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2015/07/watch-michael-fassbender-in-full-trailer-for-steve-jobs/), the vast majority of times we see him, his hair is very near his own reddish-brown color, sometimes darker, sometimes lighter.

Answer (score 11):

[The makers didn't care](http://uk.businessinsider.com/why-actor-michael-fassbender-looks-nothing-like-steve-jobs-in-aaron-sorkins-movie-2015-10?r=US&IR=T) about him looking like the real Steve Jobs:

> According to the film’s director, Danny Boyle ("Trainspotting"), the
>   decision to not have Fassbender look like Jobs was made very early on.
>
> "We were very clear right from the get-go that **this wasn't about a
>   physical impersonation at all**," Boyle told Business Insider. "It was
>   about inhabiting, it's almost Shakespearean. **He's historically
>   accurate to a degree, but then he is our version of him**, and there
>   will be other versions."
>
> Sorkin, who also spoke with Business Insider before the film premiered
>   at the New York Film Festival over the weekend, said he instantly
>   agreed with Boyle's instinct.
>
> Sorkin said **the way Fassbender looked in the new film "just isn't
>   important."**

According to [Entertainment Weekly](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/10/03/michael-fassbender-steve-jobs-ashton-kutcher):

> What did happen, however, was that the production team kept wigs and
>   makeup on hand throughout the process of making Steve Jobs. If
>   Fassbender and Boyle changed their minds and wanted to move closer to
>   Jobs’ look, beyond the brown contacts the actor wore, they had the
>   option.

According to some, [Fassbender's natural hair color is blond](http://www.writerswrite.com/watcherswatch/michael-fassbender-is-brilliant-in-steve-jobs-trailer-70120151):

> The first full-length trailer for the Danny Boyle-directed Steve Jobs
>   biopic is here and it's gripping. Michael Fassbender nails his
>   performance as the charismatic Jobs, despite not looking like him. **It
>   appears he didn't even dye his blond hair for the role.**

However, other sources describe it as light-brown or red.

Comment: The question is about why they went out of their way to die his hair to not look like the person he depicts. Quoting someone saying that it's 'just not important' is the opposite of going out of your way to affect it and thus doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Fassbender's natural hair color is not blond, it's a reddish-brown.

Comment: I like that they made him wear Brown contacts for his eye color but decided that the hair would just be a step too far

Comment: Steve Jobs is now a fictional character.  What the hell is wrong with Hollywood when they want to re-imagine real people.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths: You seem to be misunderstanding the nature of filmmaking.  The goal of Hollywood is not to mimic reality as closely as possible; it is to *make money* by producing movies that people will want to go see.  While folks who are devoted enough to the craft of making movies to visit websites like this one might care very deeply about a detail like the color of Fassbender's hair, it's hard to imagine the average moviegoer feeling the same way.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths What about portrayals of Shakespeare? Queen Victoria? Napoleon? Even if we know what a historical figure originally looked like doesn't mean we have to stick to that appearance. (I mean, Napoleon wasn't even that short.)